# Change signing certificate in Intellij IDEA for .air installer

Tags: intellij-idea

The IDE saved my configuration and I do not see a way to change it, the cert expired so I need to change it. I do not remember if I set this in a screen somewhere or I was asked for the details first time I built this, I am also unable to find the answer in the documentation.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the menu File -> Project Structure a popup will open, select Modules, then expand your main module, then select the configuration then click on Air Packaging tab

[image]